# Про innerHTML в javaScript

Tags: javascript

У меня этот скрипт работает:

```
<button class="number" id="num" onclick="getNumber()">
    1
</button>
<script>
    function getNumber(){
        alert(document.getElementById('num').innerHTML); // 1
    }
</script>
```

Но почему не работает тоже самое по классу?

```
<button class="number" id="num" onclick="getNumber()">
    1
</button>
<script>
    function getNumber(){
        alert(document.getElementsByClassName('number').innerHTML); // undefined
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что `document.getElementById` возвращает один элемент (или `null`), а `document.getElementsByClassName` возвращает коллекцию элементов (может быть - пустую).

```html
<button class="number" id="num" onclick="getNumber()">1</button>
<button class="number" id="num" onclick="getNumber()">2</button>
<script>
  function getNumber() {
    [...document.getElementsByClassName('number')].forEach(item => console.log(item.innerHTML));
  }
</script>
```

Или Вам вот это надо?:

```html
<button class="number" id="num" onclick="getNumber(this)">1</button>
<button class="number" id="num" onclick="getNumber(this)">2</button>
<script>
  function getNumber(item) {
    console.log(item.innerHTML);
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
alert(document.getElementsByClassName('number')[0].innerHTML);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за готовность помочь!